# Laravel 5.1 Form Validation Redirect With Input Problems

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've a problem with Laravel 5.1 Redirect With Input. I can't seem to get old values from submitted input.

I've been research for any post in stack overflow and still stuck in this problem.

This is my request controller

```
public function create() {
  $this->data["pageDescription"] = "Add new page.";
  $this->data["pageSubtitle"] = $this->data["pageTitle"] . " Add New";
  $this->data["formAction"] = adminRoute("page");
  return view("admin.page.form")->with("data", $this->data)->withInput(Input::old());
}
```

and this is my submitted controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  Input::flash();

  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "title" => "required|max:100",
    "url_title" => "required|max:100",
    "meta_description" => "required|max:50",
    "content_title" => "required|max:100",
    "content_description_id" => "required",
    "status" => "required|in:pending,published",
    "add_more_content" => "required|in:true,false"
  ]);

  if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
              ->with("data", $this->data)
              ->withErrors($validator)
              ->withInput();
  } else {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
}
```

It's kinda weird because when I dump Session::all() before I redirect()->back() the _old_input is exists

[image]

But when I dump Session::all() on my function create() the _old_input is empty.

[image]

Even when I skip the validation, and use

```
redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

I still got the same problem, the old values input empty

This is my form view

[image]

Anybody know what I am doing it wrong?

Thank youu

Comment: Did you get this to work? I've just encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get validation error? I'm not 100% sure, but I think `redirect()->back()` calls to the GET method of your form.

Comment: Yesss.. the validation error show, but the old values always empty.. In another case, I try to redirect to current controller and everything works well. But why in this case different controller it doesn't work..